# Communicate with Docker daemon on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, sockets, api

I want to use Docker API on Windows, but as far as I know, there are no socket files on Windows. On Linux, I can use `/var/run/docker.sock`, but how can I use Docker API on Windows?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I want to use Docker API on Windows. But as far as I know, there is no socket files on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker API is available through named pipes, Docker for Windows uses a named pipe npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine to access the REST API. You have to map the pipe to a tcp port.

You can solve this using socat:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:PORT_NUMBER ,reuseaddr,fork PIPE:\\.\pipes\docker_engine
```

After running socat map, you can connect using tcp://localhost:PORT_NUMBER

You can find more information [here](https://blog.sixeyed.com/what-you-can-do-with-docker-in-windows-server-2019-that-you-couldnt-do-in-windows-server-2016/)

PD: Some docker functionalities depends on windows versions

Comment: Please be aware that you should can do this in a Production environment, but you SHOULD have the docker socket protected with certificates because this is open to everyone on your network.